# Woocommerce, my Add to Cart button is passing through GTM as Form_Submit - how to I change this to an 'Add To Cart' style/event?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

As the question says, my 'add to cart' button on my product pages are passing through as a 'submit' button, and on the Google Tag Manager, they are passing through as a 'Form Start' > 'Form Submit'. I want to change this so that upon the click, the button style is recognised as a 'Add to Cart' button click.

I've tried to look through where I can to change this but I have not got anywhere. If it helps, my website is trevillposters.co.uk.

I'm also limited with my knowledge on this topic, so apologies for my basic understanding of code!

I've tried to look in my theme editor files. I'm not sure where I'm looking but I think it is either CSS or JS based, so I was searching these files for things like "submit" and "add_to_cart" to try and find some relevance to where I can edit. No luck (and also don't want to change things if I'm not confident on it).
I've also tried google to where a lot of my results are based on changing the button text, so irrelevant.

Comment: Hi @Luke. You can set up custom Events and Triggers in Google Tag Manager. If you follow [these examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghUwerH1fsw), you will learn more than one can write in a comment.

Comment: If you want to modify your button you need to copy the templates to your theme. Woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/ - https://woo.com/document/template-structure/  https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/8.3.0/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart